# How control ubuntu as a speaker bluetooth

Tags: shortcut-keys, bluetooth, music

I connected my phone to the PC and any sound that plays on the phone, can play and be heard in my PC speakers.

Now I want to be able to control my phone media through the computer keyboard in Ubuntu (With media keys or anything) but I can't control the musics to next sound or previous.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

Install [blueZ](https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/stacks/bluetooth/bluez/docs/) and by below commands, you can control your phone (or any bluetooth device).

For example for the **next** music:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_11_22_33_44_55_66 org.bluez.MediaControl1.Next
```

find your device MAC Address and replace with `11_22_33_44_55_66`

Note: **D-feet** can help you to see bluez data.

Finally you can **Add custom shortcut** keyboard in **setting** for run your commands.

enjoy.